# WebBrowser compatibility issue with website

Tags: c#, browser, compatibility

```cs
(new WebBrowser()).Version.ToString()  // returns 9.0.8112.16421
```

but the website I'm trying to load responds that it supports Internet Explorer 9 or newer.

If I load the page from internet explorer, there's no problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I added the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\"Application.exe"
```

as `REG_DWORD` with value **9000** in **Decimal**, to force version 9.0 emulation